# Systems of First Order Linear Equations - Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the vectors $x^{(1)}(t) = (t,1)$ and $x^{(2)}(t) = (t^2, 2t)$

I computed the Wronskian which is t^2. But I was wondering how to solve the following questions:

1) In what intervals are $x^{(1)}(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$ are independent?

2) What conclusions can be drawn about the coefficients in the system of homogeneous differential equations satisfied by $x^{(1)}(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$?

3) Find the systems of equations $x' = P(t) \cdot x$ and verify the conclusion of 2).

I am using Elementary Differential Equations and BVP textbook by Boyce but in nowhere does it teach me the techniques of finding intervals and finding $P(t)$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: When is your Wronskian $0$?

Comment: To show independence for a given $t,$ you must show that $$\alpha x^{(1)}(t)+\beta x^{(2)}(t)=\vec 0\implies \alpha=\beta=0.$$ In other words, $x^{(1)}(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$ are independent, except where the system $$\alpha t+\beta t^2=0\\\alpha+2\beta t=0$$ has a non-trivial solution $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: @VladimirVargas My Wronskian is t^2

Comment: For which t is your wronskian 0?

Comment: @VladimirVargas Well by definition of Wronskian matrix and determinant, I got t^2 and had to check to see if it's equal to 0 which is obviously not. So x^(1)(t) and x^2(t) are linearly independent.

Comment: $t^2=0$ if $t=0$. This answers your first question. I hoped you see that, but you didn't, so I say it explicitly

Comment: @VladimirVargas Oh yes, I actually saw that. Sorry I guess I just didn't understand what you exactly hinted/asked. Would you happen to know #3)? I am really stuck. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you did the 2nd point. Then I'll help you with the 3rd one.

Comment: @VladimirVargas From a) where the Wronskian is t^2, we know that the only way to make this Wronskian equal to 0 is that t=0, this means that x^(1) and x^(2) are linearly independent at each point except t=0; they are linearly independent on every interval.